# white screen webview into imageview

Tags: android

My goal it is to display some html with an image in it, in an imageView. So I created a webview, I converted this webview in bitmap and I set this imageview with the bitmap, but I have a white screen. I checked the bitmap is not null.

Do you know why I have a white screen?maybe there is a better way to do that..?

ImageViewActivity.java

```
public class ImageViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
ImageView imageView;
 Bitmap bmp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_view);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String customHtml = "<div style=\"background-image:url(pic_10.jpg);height:100%;background-repeat:no-repeat;\"><div style=\"position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%\">
```

HBase Administration Cookbook

www.amazon.com";

```
     webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", customHtml ,
     "text/html", "utf-8", null);

     webView.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);
     webView.destroyDrawingCache();
     webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     webView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(480,
     MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
     MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(800, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
     webView.layout(0, 0, webView.getMeasuredWidth(),
     webView.getMeasuredHeight());
     webView.buildDrawingCache(true);
     bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getDrawingCache());
     webView.destroyDrawingCache();     
     imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);


}

}
```

activity_image_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
 <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#ABABAB"
    android:visibility="gone"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Update string html

Answer (score 0):

I am testing your application with the answer I gave you here [Refresh activity/ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871026/refresh-activity-imageview?lq=1). No blank screen(Hbase Administration book is displayed).
Do you have the network permission in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And again your custom Html code is messed up too. You should look at the html string.
Thats where your problem is.

Comment: Yes I have this line in my manifest.I tried your answer here :[Refresh activity/ImageView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871026/refresh-activity-imageview) and I have a blank screen the first time I click on the button after it works well, but not on the first click. 
I change the html.
|| And in this case without button (for the post here), I have a blank screen.
Thanks for your help.