# Refresh activity/ImageView?

Tags: android

In my first activity I have a button and a webview and when I click on the button it opens a new activity with the content of the webview in an imageview. (I transform the webview in bitmap and set the imageview with this bitmap).

The problem is when I click on the button for the first time, nothing happen, my screen stays white. But if I come back in the first activity and reclick on the button the imageview is well displayed.

Why in the first time wasn't the imageview  displayed? Do I need something like to refresh my second activity or Imageview?

WebViewActivity.java

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    ImageView imageView;
    Button button;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.webview);

       webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
       webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       String customHtml = "<BODY BACKGROUND=\"pic_10.jpg\"><BODY><div style=\"position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%\"><div style=\"padding:24px 0 0;margin:0;height:40px;background:transparent;position:relative;\"><a href=\"http://www.amazon.com\" style=\"padding:0 140px 0 0;margin:0;height:40px;display:block;text-decoration:none;overflow:hidden;background:#fff;\" target=\"_blank\"><span style=\"padding:0 0 0 40px;margin:0;display:block;overflow:hidden;background:transparent url(http://ads.gumgum.com/com/gumgum/tests/amazon.png) no-repeat scroll left center;\"><p style=\"padding:0;margin:0;font:bold 12px/16px Arial;color:#000;text-decoration:underline;display:block;height:16px;overflow:hidden;text-align:left;padding:2px 0;word-wrap:break-word;\">HBase Administration Cookbook</p><p style=\"padding:0;margin:0;font:italic 12px/16px Arial;color:#c60;text-decoration:none;display:block;height:16px;overflow:hidden;text-align:left;word-wrap:break-word;\">www.amazon.com</p></span><span style=\"position:absolute;bottom:0;right:70px;overflow:hidden;\"><img src=\"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41OEZDHmUoL._SL75_.jpg\" style=\"border:none;max-width:64px;*width:64px;height:64px;\"></span></a></div></div>";


       webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", customHtml , "text/html", "utf-8", null);

       button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);

    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {

           webView.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);
           webView.destroyDrawingCache();
           webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
           webView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(480, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(800, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
           webView.layout(0, 0,  webView.getMeasuredWidth(),  webView.getMeasuredHeight());


            webView.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getDrawingCache());
        webView.destroyDrawingCache();
        //imageView.setMaxHeight(55);
        //imageView.setMaxWidth(20);
        Bitmap bmap_New = scaleDownBitmap(bmap,400,this);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bmap_New);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

     public static Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap photo, int newHeight, Context context) {

         final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;        

         int h= (int) (newHeight*densityMultiplier);
         int w= (int) (h * photo.getWidth()/((double) photo.getHeight()));

         photo=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);

         return photo;
         }
```

ImageViewActivity.java

```
    public class ImageViewActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_view);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_image_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I don't know if it is linked but when I start my application I have this in my catlog :

```
E/chromium(32671): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:190: [1214/103321:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(190)] StatHub::Init - App com.example.androidtestadserver isn't supported.
```

Comment: Could you show some code? It may be that the image is not yet loaded.

Comment: I added the 2 java class. You mean if I wait on the second activity the image should appears? if yes I already wait and nothing happen.

Comment: No, i mean that the image should be set when the view is done, using a callback.

Comment: Could you detailed plz? I am not sure to understand, you said I should set the image before calling the ImageViewActivity?

Comment: I thought the webview was not ready rendering when you pressed the button, but that should not matter. Have you tried to set the image on the OnResume handler? Or during Debug, what is the content of bmp?

Comment: Bitmap is not null (size : 864000) and I just tried to use OnResume() and the same result..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21106/discussion-between-germaingum-and-dmaij)

Comment: @GermainGum, posted the answer for you. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend a different approach.
Passing the entire bitmap through intent requires a lot of memory and wont work on older phone lets say SDK 2.3.
Try passing the bitmap as a byteArray and build it for display in the next activity.
If you want to pass it inbetween activities, I would store it in a file. That's more efficient, and less work for you. You can create private files in your data folder using MODE_PRIVATE that are not accessible to any other app.
By the way the following worked for me:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {

       webView.setWillNotCacheDrawing(false);
       webView.destroyDrawingCache();
       webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       webView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(480, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(800, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
       webView.layout(0, 0,  webView.getMeasuredWidth(),  webView.getMeasuredHeight());


        webView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getDrawingCache());
    webView.destroyDrawingCache();
    //imageView.setMaxHeight(55);
    //imageView.setMaxWidth(20);
    Bitmap bmap_New = scaleDownBitmap(bmap,400,this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageViewActivity.class);
    //Bitmap b; // your bitmap
    ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmap_New.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
    intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bs.toByteArray());
    //intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bmap_New);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Receiving:

```
public class ImageViewActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_view);

        Log.d("ImageViewActivity", "Oncreate");

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        //Intent intent = getIntent();
        //Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
        if( getIntent().getExtras() != null ){
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                    getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("BitmapImage"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("BitmapImage").length);  
            imageView.setImageBitmap(b);

        }
        else{
            Log.d("ImageViewActivity", "null");
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: This is weird, I just tried your code and I have still the same issue, first click on the button white screen but I go back to the first activity and re-click on button the image is well displayed..
I am going to try by file, but I don't know if this will make a difference.
(I added on line of catlog)

Comment: I understand my approach to send a bitmap by intent is not really good. So I also try without intent and i have the same issue (nothing displayed) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869967/white-screen-webview-into-imageview

Comment: yes sure I tried your code, but I have the same result..the first time I click on the button nothing is displayed but if I come back on the first activity and re-click on the button the image is well displayed.. I don't know why in the first time nothing appears..